# How to access a property of an element xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to access a property of an element of a page in xamarin forms from Android and IOS projects?

For example:

```
Button1.IsVisible = false;
```

but since the Android project.

Comment: is this a custom renderer, or just in any random page in the Android project?  Generally accessing UI elements of a page from elsewhere in the app is not a good idea.

Comment: Please, write more about the result that you want, there's many ways you can do that, custom control, messaging center from android project to pcl, but it really depends in what result that you want.

Comment: Maybe set the different things on Android or ios via OnPlatform on Xamarin could be helpful. You could set OnPlatform on xaml or code. Please check the sample in the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could access properties of page elements in the code behind file, but that is generally not a good or clean strategy.

A simple sample would be Page.xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Sample String"/>
```

And then in your  Page.xaml.cs

```
Button1.IsVisible = false;
```

The better way is that you might want to check out the **DataBinding** mechanism:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/

As a small example you would have a BindingContext/ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. With that you could go like this:

```
private bool _isVisible;
public bool IsVisible 
{
    get => this._isVisible;
    set 
    {
        if(this._isVisible != value){
            this.IsVisible;
    }
}
```

And then in your Page.xaml:

```
<Button IsVisibile="{Binding IsVisible} Content="Sample String"/>
```

You can set the BindingContext inside your Page.xaml.cs:

```
this.BindingContext = new ViewModel(); //If the properties are in a separate class (preferred)
this.BindingContext = this; //If the properties are in the page class
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I solved it with this:

```js
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "btButton1Visible", (sender) =>
                {
                    Button1.IsVisible = false;
                });
```